# Converting Culture into Locale or LCID using C#

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-2.0

I have culture given as "en-GB" or "NL-nl" but I want to get locale for it, I can't use current thread it has to be converted from culture to locale or lcid.

Not really sure what to look for on Google as nothing relevant coming up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
CultureInfo myCI = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
int lcid = myCI.LCID;
```

See [System.Globalization.CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").LCID
```

Comment: If you answer try add at least few words explaining your solution. Answers like this are automatically flag as low quality.